# Synthesising array manipulation methods in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, quartus, intel-fpga

Are array manipulation methods like `find_index()`, `find()` etc. synthesizable?

I use Quartus Prime Lite, if that helps.

Comment: @Qiu it is probably a bit out of date. Certain constructs like packages and typedefs are usually ok with modern synthesis tools. They slowly are adding sv constructs. But I do not believe that any dynamic structure would be available any time soon if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since these methods return dynamically allocated queues, they are not likely to be supported by current synthesis tools.